# How to Import Large Spreadsheet into MySQL on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I'm having trouble uploading a large spreadsheet (~250,000 records) from my computer to MySQL that is running on a VM on Google Cloud Platform.

I have normally used an upload utility to transfer files without problem, but this time the upload time is several hours and I keep losing my connection.

What's the most efficient way to get data into MySQL/GCP?  Preferably, some way that doesn't require a lot of command line gymnastics ... The simpler, the better.

Comment: Your question lack details. How big is the file? Is it already compressed? What tool are you using? What is the error? If your Internet connection is not reliable, then contact your Internet provider. Invest time into creating well thought out questions to get solid answers without guesses.

Comment: It's a 13.6MB CSV file ... ~250,000 records, not compressed.  I've been using the Excel2MySQL utility, which has been fine for uploading files before but this one is larger than usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following route to upload any type of file to your VM and it is pretty straightforward:

**1.** Create a bucket in Cloud Storage

**2.** Upload the files from your local machine to Cloud Storage bucket using

```
$ gsutil -m cp -r folder-name gs://bucketname
```

**3.** In your VM use the following command to download the files from Cloud Storage

```
$ gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucketname/folder-name local-location
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was excellent!

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a little more detail to Gray_Rhino's answer as to what I ended up doing:

1. Upload file to Google Cloud Storage bucket using Google Cloud Platform Console (Storage browser)
2. Transfer to VM using

```
    sudo gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucket-name/source-file-name.csv target-file-name.csv
```

4. Create target table in desired MySQL database
5. Import to MySQL by running following SQL statement:

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'source-file-path' INTO TABLE database.table-name
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;
```